# Create NSArray from plist array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to pull out data from a plist array and put it in an NSArray. But it seems to not be working.

Here is my main file:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"htmlData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

dictionary = tempDictionary;
[tempDictionary release];

NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
nameArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"tagName"];

self.sitesArray = nameArray;

[nameArray release];
```

My plist file. Named: htmlData.plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>tagName</key>
        <array>
            <string>&lt;html&gt;</string>
            <string>&lt;body&gt;</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It should set `self.sitesArray` equal to `@"<html>", @"<body>, nil;` but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, understand that `dictionary` and `tempDictionary` are pointing to the same object, and you cannot access the object after you release it. So when you do `[tempDictionary release]`, the dictionary is released. It cannot be then accessed through the `dictionary` pointe.

For this code, try:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"htmlData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];  
self.sitesArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"tagName"];
[dictionary release];
```

Your setter for `sitesArray` should be retaining the array, or the call to `[dictionary release]` will release it.

Comment: and the next memory managment bug is only on line away... but after this it's two lines